# execute the command string in an loop also exit when error occurs

Tags: bash

```
/usr/local/pgsql15_1/bin/psql test15  <<EOF
begin;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS special;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS numeric;
CREATE COLLATION special (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colCaseFirst=upper;colReorder=grek-latn');
CREATE COLLATION numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colNumeric=yes');
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS special;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS numeric;
commit;
EOF
```

first part is dynamic, second EOF part is static, the same. I'm trying to find a way to loop through. The following is so far what I tried.

```
VAR=$(cat<<EOF
begin;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS special;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS numeric;
CREATE COLLATION special (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colCaseFirst=upper;colReorder=grek-latn');
CREATE COLLATION numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colNumeric=yes');
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS special;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS numeric;
commit;
EOF
)
echo "$VAR"

arr_variable=("/usr/local/pgsql15_1/bin/psql test15" "/usr/local/pgsql14_5/bin/psql test14" "/usr/local/pgsql14_3/bin/psql test14")
for i in "${arr_variable[@]}"
do
   echo "$i" "$VAR"
done
```

It's kind of almost close. Expected behavior: execute/eval the concatenate string. (like the first code block) in terminal. If possible, when error occurs then the process exits, print out the error.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you change `echo "$i" "$VAR"` to `$i "$VAR"` (without the `echo`)?

Comment: You don't need `VAR=$(cat<<EOF ....)`.  You can just use a multi-line quoted string (with double-quotes since you have single-quotes inside the string and, fortunately, no variable expansions).   i.e. `VAR="multi-line string here"`.   or justy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following avoids having to rely on the shell splitting up the command strings correctly. It does this by keeping the database names and the unique parts of the `psql` executable pathnames in two separate arrays.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

statements=$(cat <<'END_SQL'
begin;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS special;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS numeric;
CREATE COLLATION special (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colCaseFirst=upper;colReorder=grek-latn');
CREATE COLLATION numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colNumeric=yes');
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS special;
drop COLLATION IF EXISTS numeric;
commit;
END_SQL
)

psql_vers=( pgsql15_1 pgsql14_5 pgsql14_3 )
databases=( test15    test14    test14    )

set -- "${databases[@]}"

for psql_ver in "${psql_vers[@]}"; do
    if ! printf '%s\n' "$statements" | "/usr/local/$psql_ver/bin/psql" "$1"
    then
        break
    fi

    shift
done
```

This creates two arrays, one for the `psql` version directory, and another one for the database names.

The database names are then transferred to the list of positional parameters, making it trivial to `shift` the first one off the list later.

In the loop, we loop over the `psql` versions, and for each, we call the appropriate executable with the first database name as the argument, sending the SQL statements on the standard input stream.  Then we `shift` off the database name from the list of positional parameters, leaving the next database name in `$1` for the next iteration to use.

The exit status of the pipeline in the loop is used to determine whether to terminate the loop prematurely through `break` or not.  Any output, be it error messages or other output, is sent to the script's standard output and error streams.